# Is there a way to automatically call a particular method immediately after all constructors have run?

Tags: c#, constructor

I want to be able to call a particular method automatically upon construction of a derived object, however I can't think how to do it. The following code illustrates. Another answer recommended OnLoad, but I am doing this for Unity on Mac and OnLoad doesn't appear to be supported by my platform. Any suggestions?

```
public class Parent {

    public Parent ()
    {
        // A. Stuff to do before child constructor code runs
        DoThisAutomaticallyAfterConstruction();
    }

    public void DoThisAutomaticallyAfterConstruction()
    {
        // C. In this example, this will run after A, before B. I want it to run ABC
    }
}

public class Child : Parent {

    public Child () : base()
    {
        // B. Stuff to do here after parent constructor code runs
    }
}
```

Comment: this is code smell to me. the base class shouldn't be concerned with derived classes.  also, constructors should set up the initialized state of the object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no built-in way to do what you want (it's a fairly-often-requested feature).

One workaround is to implement a factory pattern, where you don't create objects by calling the constructor directly, but instead implement a static method to create them for you.  For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public MyClass()
  {
    // Don't call virtual methods here!
  }

  public virtual void Initialize()
  {
    // Do stuff -- but may be overridden by derived classes!
  }
}
```

then add:

```
public static MyClass Create()
{
  var result = new MyClass();

  // Safe to call a virtual method here
  result.Initialize();

  // Now you can do any other post-constructor stuff

  return result;
}
```

and instead of doing

```
var test = new MyClass();
```

you can do

```
var test = MyClass.Create();
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I've heard of factories but this helps me understand them much more.

Comment: @RobinKing See my edited answer for a couple of pointers to more detail about the factory pattern.  The static factory method is a simple approach, but some prefer to use factory objects (and some situations require their use).

Comment: This is a very old post, but it may be useful to change the constructor to `private`, this will force clients to use the factory.

Answer (score 6):

While @Jeremy Todd's (accepted) answer works and is a widely accepted solution to the problem, it has a drawback: not very IoC and serialization friendly, since your class cannot be properly constructed using `new`. Let me introduce a general solution using some C# features. Note that this solution does not require you to use a factory pattern or invoke anything after constructing the object, and it works on any class with just implementing an interface with a single method.
First we declare an interface that our classes will have to implement:

```
public interface IInitialize {
    void OnInitialize();
}
```

Next we add a static extension class for this interface, and add the Initialize method:

```
public static class InitializeExtensions
{
    public static void Initialize<T>(this T obj) where T: IInitialize
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(T))    
            obj.OnInitialize();
    }
}
```

Now, if we need a class and all of its descendants to call an initializer right after the object is fully constructed, all we need to do is implement `IInitialize` and append a line in the constructor:

```
public class Parent : IInitialize
{
    public virtual void OnInitialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent");
    }

    public Parent()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    public override void OnInitialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child");
    }
}

public class GrandChild : Child
{
    public GrandChild()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    public override void OnInitialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GrandChild");
    }
}
```

The trick is that when a derived class calls the extension method `Initialize`, that will suppress any calls not made from the actual class.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a good candidate for a factory.  Make all the constructors private or protected, requiring consumers of your code to call the factory method when they want an instance of your object.  In the factory method, you use the `new` operator to create the object, and then call `DoThisAutomaticallyAfterConstruction()` before returning the object.

EDIT

A factory may be a static method, or you may have a factory object.  See, for example, Wikipedia on the abstract factory pattern at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern, and the documentation for the ADO.NET DbProviderFactories at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda6c36e.aspx for a real-world implementation.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example you are accomplishing **ACB**, you want to accomplish **ABC**.

In order to run code after the child constructor, you need to make the call after B (the child constructor) you cannot call the code at A (the parent constructor) then you won't accomplish ABC.

Move `DoThisAutomaticallyAfterConstruction()` at the end of the child class constructor?

Truly a strange question though.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't necessarily do the trick in an unsealed class, since even-more-derived classes could do further initialization that would take place after your child constructor has finished executing, so it's still not safe to call virtual members in the constructor.

Comment: @JeremyTodd - We would need more information from the OP if that were the case.  I am answering on the information from this post.

Comment: In normal code it is strange, but when dealing with UI code this is often necessary. But like the author said, normally we would just use the OnLoad event.

Comment: @JeremyTodd, note that this is not a virtual method call, the method is not virtual. (It *could* be a template method pattern that might invoke other virtual methods, I will grant that.) However, your larger point still holds, a further derived class GrandChild would not want Child firing off this method.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - if that is the OP's intent, no mention of other classes.

Comment: @JonH We don't know that DoThisAutomaticallyAfterConstruction() doesn't invoke virtual methods -- the information in the post is insufficient to recommend calling it in the derived class constructor.

Comment: @JeremyTodd - That is what I mentioned.