# Action after object initializer

Tags: c#, .net

I want to perform some actions during object creation, but **after** all properties are initialized. I can't use constructor because it executes **before** object initializer.

```
var product = new Product
{
    Name = "Test",
    Price = 10,
    ...
} // Automatic product.PostInitializer() method call

public class Product
{
    public required string Name { get; init; }
    public required decimal Price { get; init; }
    ...

    private void PostInitializer() { ... }
}
```

Of course, I can manually call the PostInitializer() method, but I want to be sure that the client code will call this method every time after creation.

Comment: Factory seems to be a proper way to do this kind of stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792877/c-sharp-how-to-execute-code-after-object-construction-postconstruction. If u don't want to complicate code, just use constructor: public Product(string name, decimal price) { Name = name; Price = price; PostInitialize(); } (also remove "required" from properties and leave them get-only)

Comment: *"I can't use constructor because it executes before object initializer."* - That's only true because of the constructor you have.  Do you **want** a parameterless constructor at all?  Or do you want to have only a constructor with the required parameters and perform that initialization logic within that constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a tool like that already, it's called... the constructor.

```cs
var product = new Product("Test", 10);

public class Product
{
    public required string Name { get; }
    public required decimal Price { get; }
    
    public Product(string name, decimal price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        PostInitializer();
    }

    private void PostInitializer() { ... }
}
```

Now there's no way to construct a `Product` instance without executing `PostInitializer`. This is what constructors are meant for, you should never allow a partially-initialized object to exist.